# await Task.WhenAll vs ..select(async .. => await)

Tags: c#, asynchronous

just a quick question. We're having some misunderstanding here.

we have:

```
var tasks = files.Select(async fileName => await IngestFileAsync(container, fileName));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

I say that the first line still goes concurrent, but my fellow colleague says otherwise. Besides, he says that the second `await` has no meaning, because all 
actions are already performed.

is this code then the same:

```
var tasks = files.Select(fileName => IngestFileAsync(container, fileName));
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

as:

```
var tasks = files.Select(async fileName => await IngestFileAsync(container, fileName));
var results = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Could someone shine some extra light on this?

cheers.

added:
oke, so it will run concurrent.

However, can someone add some extra info what the difference is between these code snippets:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/lzv2B7
https://dotnetfiddle.net/dMusus

(notice line 16, `async` and `await`). Is there any difference between those 2?
What I would expect is that **with** async and await it will start directly, and without, that it will start when it comes to `Await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`

added for clearity - this is my code-:

```
   private async Task<Result> IngestFilesAsync(ICloudBlobContainer container, IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Start IngestFilesAsync");

        var tasks = files.Select(fileName => IngestFileAsync(container, fileName));
        var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        _logger.LogDebug("All tasks completed");

        if (results.Any(t => t.IsFailure))
        {
            return Result.Fail(string.Join(",", results.Select(f => f.Error)));
        }

        return Result.Ok();
    }

    private async Task<Result> IngestFileAsync(ICloudBlobContainer container, string fileName)
    {
        _logger.LogDebug("Start IngestFileAsync");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);

        _logger.LogDebug("Blob retrieved");

        if (await blob.ExistsAsync())
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                _logger.LogDebug("Start download to stream");
                await blob.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
                _logger.LogDebug("To mem downloaded");

                _logger.LogDebug("Start ftp-upload");

                return await _targetFTP.UploadAsync(memoryStream, fileName);
            }
        }

        _logger.LogWarning("Blob does not exists");

        return Result.Fail($"Blob '{fileName}' does not exist");
    }
```

where `_targetFTP.UploadAsync(memoryStream, fileName);` is again a task etc. etc.

Comment: Just rewrite both cases as `foreach` loop (instead of `Select`) - and you get answer straight away

Comment: This is easy to test: make your async function `Task.Delay` and measure how long it takes.

Comment: @fidor in my logging i see duplicate lines after each other, that would suggest that they were executed concurrent. Now that i am typing it, it would be possible that there were mulltple threads that would come here.

Comment: Please unaccept my answer... the first revision was wrong and regardless, there is a better one.

Comment: @Fabio How would you re-write this code to use a foreach loop?  That'd be a pretty radical change in how the code is written.  And how would that foreach loop end up utilizing an `async` lambda, in order to determine its semantics?

Comment: @Fildor The reasoning is *identical* to the reason that the operations are performed concurrently in the second snippet.  Starting a bunch of asynchronous operation without waiting for any of them to finish will, unless the specific implementations otherwise inhibit it, result in them doing their work concurrently.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, it was cleared up in the meantime. When I tried this in a fiddle, I came to that exact conclusion and was able to follow OP's reasoning.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`async x => await f()` creates an anonymous function which returns a task. That task effectively wraps the one created by `f`: it will complete directly afterwards. In particular, this anonymous function returns an in-progress task as soon as possible.

`.Select` does not behave differently based on whether the enumeration type is one of a task. It allows the next result to be fetched directly, when the first returned task is still in progress.

The code fragments are not 100% identical, but the difference you're asking about doesn't exist.

The differences are small; the most visible change is probably in exception handling. Suppose you have two not-yet-implemented functions:

```
Task Sync() => throw new NotImplementedException();
async Task Async() => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

Here, `var task = Sync();` obviously fails immediately. But `var task = Async();` is different: that succeeds. The `async` keyword here forces a task to be created, which captures the thrown exception.

This same distinction also applies to `.Select(x => Sync())` vs `.Select(async x => await Sync())`.

Comment: oke, so, it is still concurrent. Does the second `await` => `var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` still have a meaning, or could I just use Task.WhenAll(tasks); ?

Comment: @RoelantM `Task.WhenAll(tasks)` doesn't block. It returns another task, which completes when all the original tasks complete. Just `Task.WhenAll(tasks);` therefore has no effect. But it could be `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);`, without `var results`, if you don't need the results.

Comment: so, using the await should be used, otherwise it would continue the rest of my function before all threads maybe ready. could you then explain the difference between the `select(..async .. etc)` and without the `async` and `await` in the select..?

Comment: @RoelantM Edited to cover one of the differences.

Comment: thnx! so for exceptionhandling the `.select(async .. => await)` would be a better way?

Comment: @RoelantM It depends. If the function you're calling promises to always return a task, even if it might be a failed task, then for exception handling it doesn't matter. I don't know the function you're calling.